# SQL ISJSON returning false for JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to find out why this is considered not JSON in SQL. Using JSON.stringify to send from the front end.

```
'[{\"value\":\"TB12\",\"label\":\"Tom Brady\"},{\"value\":\"TW95\",\"label\":\"Tiger Woods\"},{\"value\":\"PM10\",\"label\":\"Peyton Manning\"}]'
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Can we see how you're passing `JSON.stringify` to the database, please?

Comment: `declare @j nvarchar(max) = N'[{\"value\":\...';
select *
from openjson(json_value('["'+@j+'"]', '$[0]'))
with(value varchar(20), label varchar(50));`

Comment: @lptr Could you explain that comment, or write it up as an answer?

Comment: ..@Schwern..the string is escaped json,it is added as a scalar in a json array(it could be an object,key value) json_value() retrieves the value of the scalar, which unescapes it and it is parsed with openjson()

Answer (score 0):

Those are not escapes in SQL. You're sending literally `\"value\"` instead of just `"value"`. [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does not escape like that. Something added those escapes, perhaps you copied the JSON from a debugger?

Your database should have given you an error explaining what was wrong. [Demonstration from Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/JUi6tXpu). Be sure to check the errors from your SQL queries.